# Puput (Wagtail based blog) - Where are the files?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I've added a puput blog to an existing Django project. I followed all the steps for setting up a standalone blog app (https://puput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html).

It works fine in that I now have working blog at http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ and can edit the content and add new posts at http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog_admin/ .
But where are all the files? Specifically the template file. I don't see any new folders or files in my Django project.

I would like to edit the html template in order to get a layout that fits with my project. But I can't find any files to edit.

I how someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

puput already provides the templates (https://github.com/APSL/puput/tree/master/puput/templates/puput) so they are installed in your python path along with the puput package. You should be able find them in your /lib/site-packages/pupup/templates.

To change them *do not* edit them directly from their installation location. Instead, copy the templates you want to override in your project keeping the correct directory structure (i.e puput's blog_page.html should be copied to your templates/puput/blog_page.html) and edit them from there.